# Package to read in data from excel files

Tags: import, packages, excel

I want make a package to add a function to *Mathematica* that reads all excel files is the working directory that is set after the package is loaded.

```
BeginPackage["Reader`"]

f::usage="f[] returns data from excel file"

Begin["`Private`"]   

 f[]:=Module[{files},
    files = FileNames["*.csv",Directory[]];
    data = Import[#]& /@ files;];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

#### What is happening

Currently, if I load the package, it immediate reads any excel files in default folder.

```
<<Reader`
```

*Trouble -- excel files in default folder get read*

```
SetDirectory["somewhere"]
read=f[]
(*Result!*)
```

#### What I want

I want to load the package without reading in the excel file, so I can change the working directory before I call `f`.

```
<<Reader
```

*Package is loaded but no excel files are read*

```
SetDirectory["somewhere"]
read = f[]
(*Result!*)
```

Is possible to do what I want or do I need to define the function in a different way?

Comment: Since `f` is set delayed, after ``<<Reader` `` nothing will be imported. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but try

```
BeginPackage["Reader`"]

f::usage = "f[] imports data from CSV files in the current directory"

Begin["`Private`"]
f[] :=
  Module[{files},
    files = FileNames["*.csv"];
    Import[#] & /@ files]
End[]

EndPackage[]
```

The above code worked for me.

Be sure that all the code cells in your package are Input cells with the initialization cell property or Program cells (which get that property by default).

Comment: It was very simple, Thank you!